# Getting am image to get larger with roll over, and text when clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I am trying to get an image to get bigger with a roll over, then if clicked display text, and clicking on the image again with make the text go away. I am unable to get the text part to work. I can only get the image to get bigger with a roll over. Here is my HTML and JS codes.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="picturetask.js"> </script> 
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Picture Manipulation</h1>
<center>
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="../images/hippo.png" alt="Hippo" height="200" id=hippo>
<div id=hippos>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</head>
```

JS:

```
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "410px";  
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "200px";
}
function handleClickPar() {
     document.getElementById("hippos").innerHTML = "Picture of a Hippo." ;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any `click` events to trigger `handleClickPar()` You can also hide/show or you can remove the text and insert the text by checking the current state. A simple if condition will work here.

Comment: Take a look at your HTML structure. the `head` element shouldn't contain the `body` element. You need to declare a default doctype and add the mandatory `title` element within your `head` element. Also, the `<div id=hippos>` should be written `<div id="hippos">`

Comment: @JeffNoel Most browsers have always accepted (and HTML5 now explicitly allows) unquoted attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing on `onclick` to make `handleClickPar()` do anything.

In that function, check to see if `hippo` is empty - if so, set the text. If not, clear it out.

```js
function bigImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "410px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
  x.style.height = "200px";
}

function handleClickPar() {
  var el = document.getElementById("hippos");

  if (el.innerHTML.trim())   // if it's not empty or whitespace
    el.innerHTML = "";       
  else
    el.innerHTML = "Picture of a Hippo.";
}
```

```html
<div id=hippos>
</div>

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onclick="handleClickPar();" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="Hippo" height="200" id=hippo>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct html document structure is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="yourscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Put your content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

And use onclick="" for your handleClickPar() function.